# Django Rest Framework - Register Multiple Viewsets Against a Single URL, Based on Header Data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I need to use Multiple **ViewSets** with the same URL where the active **ViewSet** needs to be selected dynamically based on request **header** logic. Django rest framework allows you to do this to register the **viewsets** against different urls:

```py
router.register(r"type_1", Type1ViewSet, basename="type_1")
router.register(r"type_2", Type2ViewSet, basename="type_2")
```

However, in my case, the viewsets are very similar. So I'd like to do this in the `urls.py` file:

```py
if request.header['flag'] is True:
    router.register(r"type", Type1ViewSet, basename="type_1")
else: 
    router.register(r"type", Type2ViewSet, basename="type_2")
```

In my case, the following wouldn't work:

- Using a single `ViewSet` but picking different `Serializers` from the header logic instead of dealing with multiple ViewSets.

Is there a way to get access to the `request` object in the `urls.py` so that I can use it to orchestrate my conditional? If not, how this can be achieved?

Comment: I'm wondering if this isn't Django anti pattern ? see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294062/django-dynamic-urlpatterns)

Comment: @ChihebNexus Yes, you're correct. The reason is laid out in this statement: `URLs are not loaded dynamically for every user, they are parsed and loaded on application startup, so you cannot put per-request logic in there. In general, this logic should be handled in your view.`

Answer (score 3):

You can't achieve what you want, using two different views for the same route is impossible.

However, if the only thing changing between your two viewsets is the serializer, just use the method `get_serializer_class`.

```py
class YourViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # Your attributes ....

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.header['flag'] is True: # your condition
            return Type1Serializer
         return Type2Serializer
```

Comment: This is the way to go OP. If you want 2 vastly different services on the same endpoint, you'll have to put that logic into the action itself, using a `if` condition and 2 different serializers. Even more so because URLs are generated at launch, so you kind have no choice.

Comment: also you will lose the auto swagger schema generation using this approach, if you are using drf_yasg or similar